# Multivariable calculus partial derivative chain rule question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Consider the function $(,,)=(^2+5,^2−2)$
for some function  of two variables.

Show that  necessarily satisfies the relation:

$((−10^2−4)\frac{∂}{∂}−(4^2−10)\frac{∂}{∂})=ℎ(,,)\frac{∂}{∂} $

where ℎ(,,) = ?

I am having a lot of trouble with this question and I really don't know where to begin. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You should begin by  computing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$

Comment: They are just asking you to calculate $$\dfrac{(−10z^2−4xy)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}−(4x^2−10yz)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}}$$It may be a bit of a pain, but it is a straight-forward calculation.